# Add new item in Visual Studio

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, wizard

In eclipse the Add New Class wizard lets you specify all sorts of options, such as what modifiers the class has, what interfaces it implements, what its parent class(es) is, what package it resides in, etc.

Comparatively the default add new item wizard in visual studio while offering a large selection of templates does not offer such options.

Is there any way to get eclipse like functionality in Visual Studio through some setting or extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio has a different way of handling things. You add the class and then use the refactor menu to add any interfaces, etc. Right click on the class name -> refactor, or you can use the refactor menu.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio should have those capabilities right off the start, I would suggest going through the different menu such as Views, projects etc. take a look at this 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc136611.aspx if your new that is